# Exporting DNN Form & List Forms to a new site

Tags: forms, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-module

I'm creating a new website with DNN and have a lot of forms to move over from the old version of the site to the new one. Is there a way to export the forms themselves (Schema Definition) from the old site and then import them into the Form & List module on the new site?

I see there is an option to export the user submitted data, but that's not what I need. I need to export the forms themselves.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.  "Export Content" will export all of the content, which includes the form definitions.